# Get text from <span> within a <div> with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I get the text (`02/10/2020`) inside the span blocks with Selenium?

```
<div class="unique_class_date">
  <span>02/10/2020</span>
</div>
```

I tried with

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("unique_class_date")
```

but it returns empty.

**Edit**: this is the code, I am trying to get data from Bloomberg:

```
import selenium.webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options as FirefoxOptions
options = FirefoxOptions()
options.headless = True
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox(options=options)
dateclass = "time__245ca7bb"

url = "https://www.bloomberg.com/quote/TSLA:US"
driver.get(url)
last_update = driver.find_element_by_class_name(dateclass).text # sadly, this returns empty
...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should target the `<span>` child

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".unique_class_date > span").text
```

If this doesn't work either you can use `get_attribute()`

```
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(".unique_class_date > span")
element.get_attribute("textContent")
#or
element.get_attribute("innerText")
```

Answer (score 0):

Add **.text** at the end.

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name("unique_class_date").text
```

Comment: Sorry, yep I tried that already. I should have said `driver.find_element_by_class_name("unique_class_date").text` returns empty.
Thanks!

Comment: Ah. Would you mind showing the whole code? Or at least the part where it's being used.